# Windows 10 Bash and python paths

Tags: python, windows, bash, path, pythonpath

I've recently installed the windows bash. I tryed to make the packages installed with Anaconda visible by adding them to the PYTHONPATH variable but it is not listed in the environment.

Couriously enough sys.path.append works just fine and has entries, as [sys.path doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) states that the package variable is instatiated from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, but how can it be if it is not present in the environment (Bash of windows)?

I've already checked the windows environment and they're as separated system (otherwise the Anaconda packages would be available for import). So where can I set the python paths to new modules in windows bash?

Answer (score 1):

If you are launching python from windows bash it won't automatically find your PYTHONPATH environment variable from windows. You need to add it yourself. You can do this by editing the .bashrc file. It is located in your home directory (/home/userid or just ~).

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Now add the following line:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/mnt/c/my/python/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some IDE like PyCharm, it may create it's own PYTHONPATH. It certainly won't be visible from system.

You may create PYTHONPATH variable on your own from system settings (Control Panel etc). But if something like IDE then replace it locally, your modules won't be able to import.

The stable but a bit rude way is modify the windows registry by modifying a value in PYTHONPATH record.

The code that uses [RapidEE](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download) utility (RAPIDEE_EXECUTABLE is path to your rapidee.exe) to achieve that

```
def set_pythonpath():
    subprocess.call([RAPIDEE_EXECUTABLE, '-S', '-C', 'PYTHONPATH', YOUR_PACKAGE_PATH])
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not using pycharm, just trying to import from an instance of python spawning from the bash. I've already tryed to add a variable (by the way the rapidEE seems much better than the panels labirinth option, thx!) but BASH environment variables are separated from the Windows environment variables. Anaconda uses windows environment variables and in a Windows terminal all is importable correctly. I'd like to know where the sys.path is initiated by the linux subsystem python version (yeah 2 pythons) as in absences of a PYTHONPATH variable I have no clue of where to append my paths.