# Windows bash shell shows the wrong version of Python

Tags: python, windows

I have installed python version 2 and 3 in windows 10 through anaconda package. Using `python --version`, CMD shows the version of python as `3`, but Windows `bash` shell shows it as `2`.

How can I activate python version 3 in Windows bash shell?

I need to activate it because I want to run commands in shell, for instance pyinstaller. CMD does not recognize pyinstaller.

Comment: This problem might occur if you have not set the environment variable properly
Here is how you can do it https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Comment: I would also like to know how you start the python shell in the bash.  Do you write python3 ?

Comment: python --version

Comment: Try starting the shell calling python3

Comment: That's my problem! How to start bash shell which calls python3 automatically.

Comment: Is your environment variable set properly?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: @t_e_o Your link doesn't say anything about the `bash` shell.

Comment: Ok,maybe this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617029/windows-10-bash-and-python-paths

Comment: Are you using Conda?

Comment: For what purpose? I use anacoda and jupyter notebook. I also use bash and cmd for installations

Answer (score 3):

bash in Windows runs on the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which has a version of Ubuntu running on it. It has its own filesystem and its own libraries and binaries for Python, so it is not using the versions of Python you installed in Windows.  You can see this by typing `which python` in bash.  It will return `/usr/bin/python` which is a location in the Subsystem for Linux filesystem, not in the normal Windows filesystem.

In bash (as in Ubuntu) you launch Python 2 with the command `python` and you launch Python 3 with the command `python3`.

If Python 3 is not present in your bash install, you can add it from the package repositories by running the command `sudo apt install python3` in bash.

Comment: It is nonstandard to invoke `python3` using `python`, so this is technically the most correct. I myself do however create that mapping, as I try to not use python 2.x as much as possible. You might also include a note about setting the environment variables in bashrc to achieve this functionality.